# Creating test for an asynchronous method

Tags: javascript, node.js, callback, aws-lambda

So I have been developing some codes using AWS Lambda with NodeJS 6.10. Because of my lack of knowledge in integration testing (don't worry, the unit tests are done), I didn't test my code. Of course, I missed a bug that caused two sleepless nights. It keeps running even after I put in this

```
return workerCallback(err);
```

I thought it would stop the function from running other codes past the if clause because I returned it. Anyway, I was able to fix my issue by adding a return just after the asynchronous function

```
SQSService.deleteMessage
```

is called. The rest of the codes did not run and the lambda function ran and ended as expected.

Here are now the code that works as expected.

```
function myFoo(currentRequest,event, workCallback){

    var current_ts = moment();
    var req_ts = moment(currentRequest.request_timestamp);

    if (req_ts.diff(current_ts, 'minutes') > 5) {
    SQSService.deleteMessage(event.ReceiptHandle, function(err, data){
        if (err) {
            return workerCallback(err);
        } else {
            return workerCallback(null, "Request stale! Deleting from queue...");
        }
    }); //end of SQS Service
        return; //This line... this line!
    }

    /* Codes below will execute because the code above is asynchronous
       but it should not as the asynchronous code above is a terminator function 
    from a business logic point of view
    */

    //more codes that will run should currentRequest.request_timestamp is 5 minutes past

 }
```

Can someone please guide me on how to test this code or create a test that would at least prevent me from doing the same mistake again? I'd like to avoid these mistakes from happening again by testing. Thanks!

Comment: remember - the call to SQSService.deleteMessage includes a callback handler - and it is in this callback handler that your two return statements exist.  These terminate the callback handler whenever the SQSService method decides to invoke it.  But they don't get executed within myFoo - so after you make the call to SQSService.deleteMessage, the code will just continue.  As for testing it, I suppse you could put an assertion or throw an Error after code that you think shouldn't ever get past.  But that's not really a systemic solution.  The larger question is why you had code after at all.

Comment: ah yes... the function receives messages with or without project_ref_no. So, if project_ref_no is undefined, delete the message and done. I suppose I could add an else for the if clause. How would you write it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(I'm moving it to an answer so the comments thread doesn't fill up - and so I can type more).

The key is to get the proper grasp of async-ness in your code.  `myFoo` seems to be asynchronous, so you need to decide whether all errors or failure modes should be handled as errors passed to its callback handler, or whether some types of error should return synchronous errors to the caller of `myFoo` itself.  My general approach is, if any errors are going through the callback handler, to have them all go there - with the minor exception of certain types of bad-coding errors (e.g. passing in things of the wrong type, or passing in null for arguments that should always have variables) which I might `throw Error()` for.  But if this kind of error (`project_ref_no == null`) is the kind of error that you should handle gracefully, then I'd probably pass it through to the error handler.  The general idea is that, when you call myFoo, and it returns, all you know is that some work is going to get done at some point, but you don't know what is going to happen (and won't get a result in the response) - the response will come back later in the call to the callback handler).

But, more importantly, it's key to understand what code is being run immediately, and what code is in a callback handler.  You got tripped up because you mentally imagines the internally generated callback handler (passed to `SQSService.deleteMessage`) was being run when you called myFoo.

As for testing strategy, I don't think there's a silver bullet to the issue of mistaking asynchronous calls (with callback handlers) with code that is run synchronously.  You could sprinkle assertions or `throw Error()`'s all over the place (where you think code should never get to), but that'd make your code ridiculous.

Typescript helps with this a bit, because you can define a function return type, and your IDE should give you a warning if you've got code paths that don't return something of that type (something most/all? typed languages give you) - and that would help somewhat, but it won't catch all cases (e.g. functions that return void).

If you're new to javascript and/or javascript's asynchronous models, you might check out the following link:

https://medium.com/codebuddies/getting-to-know-asynchronous-javascript-callbacks-promises-and-async-await-17e0673281ee

Comment: Will reply as I am trying to understand your answer. Hopefully this does not mean I abandoned the question. Thanks!

Comment: I change the code to make it more focused on the business logic. I just didn't know that after invoking an async, the codes after that will still run. I think it's a fundamental way of thinking of how to code async functions. I did assume that calling workerCallback again is something that will close the function. I updated the codes by the way.

Comment: Just to be clear, async is a keyword that has specific meaning in JavaScript.  A method is asynchronous if it makes a call that is asynchronous (e.g. an asynchronous IO call, or some other function that takes a callback handler and promises to do something with it later).   The ‘async’ keyword before a function definition allows you to code with asynchronous methods that really return Promise<XXX> as though it is a synchronous method that returns something of type XXX.  In essence, it “blocks” the calling code until the called code’s promise is resolved.  You’re not using async in your code.

Comment: Yes I am not. That should clear things out. As for promises, I am not surprised that that's going to be mentioned here. I was trying to understand first how asynchronous functions before I dive to promises. Thanks for the inputs though

Comment: Old-style asychronous programming passed in callback handlers that were expected to handle the (later) result.  Promises return a handle to the (delayed) result to the caller, so the caller can do what it wants with it (wait on it, collect a few and wait on them together, pass them to some other code, etc.), and async/await builds on Promises and lets calling code effectively "block" on the result and pretend it was synchronous (while letting other 'threads' do work in the interim).

Comment: Thank you. I hope some other devs can get insights in this post.